# Moving Thunderbird data from 16.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS; alternate solution (default/default-release)

Tags: thunderbird, migration

I had an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system running Thunderbird 68.10, and built an entirely new system with 20.04 LTS, which is also running Thunderbird 68.10 out of the box.

In moving all mail from the old system to the new system, these are the resources I looked at:

https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2019/01/14/moving-to-a-profile-per-install-architecture/

https://support.mozilla.org/gl/questions/1264072

However, when following the instructions (putting things in the default-release), some odd behavior happened.  Notably, I'd see some of my IMAP email appear on the first startup of Thunderbird, but on the next startup, the accounts were there, but all email didn't appear.

The AskUbuntu world mentions the migration stuff here:

[Backup thunderbird using Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258088/backup-thunderbird-using-ubuntu)

[Thunderbird and Firefox "profiles" disappear when using updated versions of software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262443/thunderbird-and-firefox-profiles-disappear-when-using-updated-versions-of-soft/1262450#1262450)

It seems the cleanest way I've found so far to get this to all work is to copy the *entire* .thunderbird directory to the new machine, not just the profile folder,  but this doesn't seem to be noted anywhere.

Didn't know if this was a bad thing in any way; I've got everything backed up, but was wondering if there were any issues with this.

I was running 16.04 LTS for a long time, and so originally, I was probably running a pre-67 version of Thunderbird at one point (I've got a xxxxxxxx.default for the profile, not xxxxxxxx.default-release), am curious if that had any effect.

Comment: Did you select the profile with `thunderbird -p`?

Comment: I have copied and pasted the .thunderbird directory several times over different ubuntu spin-offs and ubuntu-versions and have never encountered serious problems. Occasionally one has to upgrade some of extensions or themes used.

Comment: The profile was selected in profiles.ini, and the xxxxxxx.default-release was the one with the latest timestamp.  All the data was in the xxxxxxxx.default-release directory, which was visible.  Things work, but I'm always concerned that something will bite back if setting up something wrong.   @Bendard Decock - thanks; I'm thinking that this might be an alternate way to transfer things that isn't mentioned.

Comment: I backup the entire .thunderbird and migrate that. It's the safest and most successful way that I've used. I usually tar it and then untar it on the new machine.

Comment: I have always copied entire Firefox & Thunderbird profiles. But new versions have a different profile structure and give error messages. So I always start Thunderbird, and then edit new profile with old profile's XXX.default, now in two places.